# Why do some open-source licenses have a clause stating that one can't violate the law?

Tags: license, law

Example of such a clause in the [Creative MLOpen RAIL-M dated August 22, 2022](https://huggingface.co/spaces/CompVis/stable-diffusion-license) used by [runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5](https://huggingface.co/runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5):

> You agree not to use the Model or Derivatives of the Model:
>
> - In any way that violates any applicable national, federal, state, local or international law or regulation.

I don't see the point of that clause. I.e., I don't see what would change if the clause were to be deleted. Why do some open-source licenses have a clause stating that one can't violate the law?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't believe that license is an open source license, at least as defined by this site; the restrictions in Appendix A would appear to me to be a violation of the "No Discrimination Against Fields of Endeavor" clause of the OSD.

Comment: @PhilipKendall where was is stated that https://opensource.stackexchange.com/ follow the OSD definition? (No intent to argue, just curious, since I agree with that Appendix A violate the OSD definitions)

Comment: The [Help Center on topic page](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "As a general rule, we use the FSF's four freedoms and the OSI's open source definition as a guide to what is considered to be in the scope of "free and open"."

Comment: @PhilipKendall thanks! I reposted the question in Law.SE: [Why do some licenses have a clause stating that one can't violate the law?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/92218/31). I don't have enough rep to close it here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author has indicated that he'd like it closed.